# Visual Studio 2017 does not supportC11 new feature _Generic

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c11

Can anybody advise why Visual Studio 2017 does not support the C11 new feature `_Generic`? I found it is a very useful feature but cannot used in Visual Studio 2017.

Below is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MYTYPE(X) _Generic((X),\
int:"int",\
float:"float",\
double:"double",\
default:"other")

int main(void)
{
      int d = 5;
      printf("%s\n", MYTYPE(d));
      printf("%s\n", MYTYPE(2.0*D));
      return 0;
}
```

The complier will give below warnings and errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>predef.c
1>c:\users\mia\documents\c\listing 16.13\project1\project1\predef.c(11): warning C4013: '_Generic' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>c:\users\mia\documents\c\listing 16.13\project1\project1\predef.c(11): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
1>c:\users\mia\documents\c\listing 16.13\project1\project1\predef.c(12): error C2065: 'D': undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\mia\documents\c\listing 16.13\project1\project1\predef.c(12): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
1>Done building project "Project1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Apparently Microsoft has not yet implemented this in their C compiler.

Comment: VS 2019 16.8 has added C11 and C17 support https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/, including `_Generic`. "With the advent of two new compiler switches, /std:c11 and /std:c17, we are officially supporting the latest ISO C language standards."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 does not support any C11 features. You can plug **Intel C compiler** into Visual Studio (which supports C11) or use **Clang** or **Gcc**.

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-c11-or-c99-in-Visual-Studio-2017/answer/Dusan-Jovanovic-3) answer:

> - To your Visual Studio add the inbuilt **CLANG** support
> - Create new project
> - In project properties (General) for “Platform Toolset” select “Visual Studio 2017 - Clang with Microsoft CodeGen (v141_clang_c2)
> - In C/C++ “Language” section open the “C language” standard list , where you will find all the C standards relevant todayL C89, C99, C11
>     …select the one you wish
>
> After this (same as ever) VS2017 will compile files with “.c”
>   extension as C, and “.cpp” extension as C++.
>
> Do not forget that one can change the properties on the per file basis
>   too.

Comment: Well, technically, they *do* support C11 features since C++17 defers to C11 for some of its stuff. However, C++17-compliant compilers are only required to support certain features from the C11 *library* and generic macros are not covered by that.

Answer (score 7):

This is because Microsoft has never prioritized conformance to the C language standard. Over the last 20 years or so, their main focus has been C++. So Visual Studio is to be regarded as a C++ compiler.

In "C mode", it still has questionable compliance towards the first C standard C90. It took them forever to make an attempt to get C99 compliance, they made some effort towards that only in recent years. It is still not fully C99 compliant either. As far as I know, there are no plans for C11 or C17 compliance.

So if standard conformance is important to you, you must look for another C compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's useful for me.

Comment: I seem to recall that MS have quite often made it clear that, though their product *started* as "a C/C++ compiler", it is now focussed on C++. That means they only need to support the stuff required by the C++ standard (including certain *library* features from C11). It's natural that they deprioritise C stuff that's not necessary.

Comment: @paxdiablo And yet those libraries are not C++ compliant. For example they don't support all format specifiers required by `std::printf`/`cstdio`.

Comment: No doubt. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/07/announcing-msvc-conforms-to-the-c-standard/ - guess Microsoft's definition of the word "conform" is slightly different to mine :-)

Comment: Microsoft's understanding of conforming undoubtedly is that Microsoft tries to make the world conform to them.

Comment: C++11 through C++20 are supported in recent versions of MSVC toolchain. C11 and C17 are added in VS 2019. Checkout the conformance table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance.