# Why is this macro compiler dependent?

Tags: c, gcc, integrity

I am developing some multidevice programs, and I need a macro that helps detect changes in a variable. I would like to use this macro  to detect triggers in a var:

```
#define TRIG_UP(X)          ({  \
                                static  typeof(X) __val_ant=0; \
                                unsigned char __trig = (X) && !__val_ant; \
                                __val_ant = (X); \
                                (__trig );\
                            })
```

to use in statements like:

```
if (TRIG_UP(var1))
    var2 = TRIG_UP(var3);
```

compiling with the last GCC and arm-gcc it works great, but with other compilers (Visual Studio or Integrity) I get some errors in the declaration. My question is, why does this macro depend on the compiler? Is this depending on the standard of the language C? How can I make it compatible with all situations?

Thank you all!

Errors I get are like these:

```
error #29: expected an expression
      var2 = ({
```

or

```
 error C2059: syntax error : '{
```

depending on the compiler.

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: I added them to the description

Answer (score 5):

Because `typeof` isn't standard C but a gcc extension. You could try to rewrite it using standard `_Generic` instead.

Furthermore, identifiers starting with double underscore `__` are reserved for the standard library implementation and shouldn't be used in other code.

Comment: OP: as long as Visual Studio doesn't support C11 features (like `_Generic`), this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51960928/1606345

Comment: @DavidRanieri You can't AFAIK use Visual Studio to compile standard C, since it isn't a conforming compiler.

Comment: @Lunidn thats why I suggest to plug Intel C compiler into Visual Studio (or switch to gcc / CLang)

Comment: Additionaly, the `({})` syntax is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) as well.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks foir your answer. Doesn't matter if I change typeof to int, for example. The double underscore it was just to clarify that are internal variables, in the real macro I don't use them.

Comment: @Quentin, you are totally right, maybe is due to the `({})` is a GCC extension it is not compatible with other compilers.